# What is wrong with this JSON file? - valid JSON file

Tags: json, syntax

I've been given the JSON code below and have been asked to explain what is wrong with the code. I have used the JSON parser at http://www.jsonlint.com/ and the parser says it is a valid JSON file so i'm not sure whats wrong with it.

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with this file or where i can find a resource that will explain and answer my question.

```
{  
   "coord":{  
      "lon":-83.45,
      "lat":39.89
   },
   "sys":{  
      "type":1,
      "id":2164,
      "message":0.004,
      "country":"US",
      "sunrise":1472036117,
      "sunset":1472084182
   },
   "weather":[  
      {  
         "id":800,
         "main":"Clear",
         "description":"sky is clear",
         "icon":"01n"
      }
   ],
   "base":"stations",
   "main":{  
      "temp":17.8,
      "pressure":1023,
      "humidity":88,
      "temp_min":16,
      "temp_max":19.44
   },
   "visibility":16093,
   "wind":{  
      "speed":3.6,
      "deg":170
   },
   "clouds":{  
      "all":1
   },
   "dt":1472028028,
   "id":4517009,
   "name":"London",
   "cod":200
}
```

Comment: There does not appear to be anything wrong with it (unless you expected the data to be in XML instead, or to contain `"earthquakes"` item, or something else that is not related to JSON format).

Comment: That's valid JSON, maybe there's something wrong with your code how you parse it.

Comment: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ says it's valid for multiple RFCs. What is supposed to be wrong ?

Comment: it parses correctly. i was thinking that maybe the objects and records could have a more extensive level syntax applied to it? like encasing each object and record with the curly braces?

Comment: Its valid JSON, whoever has given this JSON to  explain what is wrong, I think just want to check that you can validate it or not.

Answer (score 0):

You should say: nothing. Sometimes being certain you're right is better than no answer.